# JS and type.match as file mime type - need advice

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, file-io, fileapi

Today I faced an interesting thing as FF File API and separate files by their types. OK here is a little snippet as

```
if (!input.files[0].type.match('image.*')) {
            window.alert("Select image please");
            return;
        }
```

it controls image being read only. But what about doc files and pdf for example? I couldn't find useful examples for this thing so I hope you can share some snippets. The thing I am interested in detecting different file types but how can I control different file types with JS and its type.match bound?

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files) is the base code

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure this works? The type attribute is supposed to be `file` no? And the type your referring to is the `accept` attribute http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/accept which can take any MIME type value.

Comment: Yes, it works and makes NOT TO get files except images only. But I want to see how to do the same for document or a pdf file?

Comment: Emm... Thank you for the link. the ("text/html", "image/x-rgb", or "application/java") maybe that is the point. I am not pretty sure is it the accept file attribute because the JS is using image.* for its if operator :( So I need your advice what should I look at?

Comment: Well, from what i understand, `.match(image.*)` matches every string that is image[something]. But to help me reproduce your case, i'll need the html/js providing the input object.

Comment: OK I have just edited my question. Watch it please

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So the base idea is that this code uses File Objects, for more info on them see :

- http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ (the spec)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File (Mozilla implementation)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader

As specified per [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-type), the `type` attribute of the File object is a MIME type. This is defined in the [RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt). But the spec itself isn't the most interesting part, what's more interesting is the list of the existing MIME type [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) or the most used one [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type#List_of_common_media_types).

In this code, they use the `type` attribute and execute a regexp on it (see [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info). Their regexp says that it's ok if the type contains `image`.

To make your own selector, you'll have to combine the above. (some of the example use === instead of match because the mime type is the entire type)
For example the following check are possible:

- document (not pdf only, odt have this type as well for example) : `input.files[0].type==='application/pdf'`
- audio  : `input.files[0].type.match('audio.*')`
- video : `input.files[0].type.match('video.*')`

And so on.

After that you can use a selector on the `name` attribute of the file if you wish to match only certain extension (for example to check between different kind of document, you could look if it's a .pdf, a .odt ...) using for example `input.files[0].name.match('\.pdf')`.
But imho that's not advised, as the user could easily play with that (removing or changing them).

Comment: Great - i added the 'video' one to my existing 'image

Comment: 'image' one and it worked a charm!  if(!file.type.match(/^image\//) && !file.type.match(/^video\//)){ };

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this isn't a 100% complete solution. For example, `file.type` of a sample .mkv file I have is an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

```
file.mimetype.match('text.*|image.*|application.*')
```

This checks for all acceptable mime types

Answer (score 0):

This matches `*/*`. It requires at least one character before and after `/`

`/(.+)\/.+/`

Results:

**image/jpeg**

<strike>imagejpeg</strike>

<strike>application</strike>

<strike>image/</strike>

<strike>jpg</strike>

<strike>/jpeg</strike>

**application/x-abiword**

**application/vnd.amazon.ebook**

**application/x-bzip2**

**application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document**

**application/epub+zip**

**application/vnd.apple.installer+xml**