# Get Original file type using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file, validation

How can I check the file type (original type) with JQuery? I mean even if I change the file format manually from .pdf to .jpg, I should get .pdf because this file is PDF document not picture. I am using the following code for checking file type :

```
var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'];
if ($.inArray(file_input.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
  alert("Wrong format!");       
}
else {
  alert("Correct format!");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of file extension before uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check file type when form submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977084/check-file-type-when-form-submit)

Comment: i don't have any idea is it possible or not?? But if just need the current file extension then `var ext = fileName.split('.').pop();` will be okey.

Comment: upvote - Cause this is a unique question, if it is possible then i will make a note of it.

Comment: Thanks guys but I have already seen all above given links but all of them just checking the extension from file name but not real file format. Is there any suggestion how to achieve this goal? Thanks!

Comment: I think the only reliable way of fetching the `mime-type` would be on the server so perhaps an AJAX request is necessary to return the `mime-type` from the server.

Comment: I am not sure if client side JavaScript would allow you to do this. But you will have to read the metadata (the header for example) of a given file to determine its type. However, there is no standard, to my understanding. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177922/how-to-determine-file-type

Comment: @Stack0verflow How can I validate the file content with PHP without uploading it into directory? I tried to get temp file location after selecting file with file input but got an error.

Comment: @UmidjonUrunov : using jquery itself, you can get the filetype and you can then use it to validate your code, check my answer below or the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @UmidjonUrunov, This may help you. [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

Comment: I have no experience at all in PHP. I am in the .NET world.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the JS from @Drakes answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload?answertab=active#tab-top).

**I've posted the JQuery Implementation for the same below :**

```js
$('#show').on("click", function() {
  var files = $("#your-files")[0].files[0];
  var temp = "";
  temp += "<br>Filename: " + files.name;
  temp += "<br>Type: " + files.type;
  temp += "<br>Size: " + files.size + " bytes";
  $('#details').html(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="your-files" multiple>
<button id="show">
  Show Details
</button>
<div id="details">
</div>
```

You can then use the file type that you get using the above jQuery in the control statements of the code posted in your question.

Comment: OP said that he would like to get file type information without relying on the extension of the file name.

Comment: @Stack0verflow : The above snippet gives the correct file type irrespective of the extension of the file name.

Comment: It does not when I try it multiple times.

Comment: @stark, I changed extension of jar file to .txt means original file is jar but i changed to text file manually so file type should be come jar but is showing only text/plain so its not working. can you update your answer?