# What is the prefix "application/" for input type file in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, vba, file-type

As per my understanding,
when I upload **.xlsx** file from pc which has installed MS Excel it gives me type= **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** and when I upload same file from pc which has not MS Excel installed it gives me type=**""**.
The following jquery code checks twice in if condition as **inputFile.type="application/"**

```
 $("#btnUpload").change(function () {
        var inputFile = $(this).get(0).files[0];
        if (inputFile != undefined || inputFile != null) {
            if (inputFile.type == ".csv" || inputFile.type == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || inputFile.type == "application/vnd.ms-excel") {
                $("#uploadedFileName").html(inputFile.name)
            } else {
                errorToast("Please select valid file format");
            }
        } else {
            errorToast("Please select file");
        }
    });
```

Please help me out with the role of **application/** prefix.
or correct my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

you are talking about different MIME types. Here is a complete list of mime types:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

"application/" has different options as you can see. If the PC does not have any excel installed it should not affect the file type you are talking about.

Here is an other question that should help you out:
[JS and type.match as file mime type - need advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395548/js-and-type-match-as-file-mime-type-need-advice)

Comment: I got your point all about MIME type but why there was a empty string for that case though I was uploaded the same file?

Comment: maybe it's related to the file name. Do you know what is the full name of the file (with the extension)?

Comment: Yes I know.It's just a regular file name- SampleOnBoardEmployeeImport.xlsx
and though I have same OS on both the systems(If you think OS will affect somehow).