# Select image format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, api, format, selector

I am using web scraper api to get title, image and description of different websites. The thing I want to do is to get images with a specific  format.. e.g. only get images that has jpg format extension .. I am trying to do that using js with if else.. here is the code and is not working

```
if(!(image.src == '[src*=".jpg"]')){
    console.log('No pic')
  }else{
    image.src = data.image;
  }
```

Comment: `[src*=".jpg"]` looks like a CSS selector. Why not use that in `document.querySelectorAll('[src*=".jpg"]')`?

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something like this:

```
if(!image.src.includes('jpg')) {
  console.log('No pic');
} else {
  image.src = data.image;
}
```

You could probably add an `|| !image.src.includes('.jpeg')` to harden it up a little bit.

Or (as mentioned in the comments) simply `querySelectorAll` for all of the `jpg` image elements then you don't need this check above at all:

```
const imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('[src*=".jpg"]');
```

Comment: Worked.. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains for that:

```
if(!(image.src.contains("jpg")){
    console.log('No pic')
 }else{
    image.src = data.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to know without understanding the API you are using, but generally you would want to be checking the MIME type of the file / image (if the API gives you that option). In your specific case the MIME type would be images/jpeg.

This question / answers may help - [JS and type.match as file mime type - need advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395548/js-and-type-match-as-file-mime-type-need-advice)